# Making a countdown to a time every day

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer

what i want is an app that countdowns to the same time everyday
for example the code tells it to countdown to a certain time that is coded into the app and cannot be changed by user input.
what I've got is code to make it countdown to a specific time and date however this is not on a everyday repeat
so what I'm looking for is so that today it would countdown to 22:02 and tomorrow it would also countdown to 22:02.
i have tried everywhere google, youtube, but cannot find it anywhere.
i will also add my code so that hopefully you can tell me where I'm going wrong.

my view controller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

NSDate *destinationDate;
IBOutlet UILabel *datelabel;
NSTimer *timer;

}

@end
```

my view controller.m

```
-(void) updateLabel {

NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
int units = NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
[datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c: %d%c", [components minute], ' ', [components second], ' ']];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1384121134];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: How is this related to the fact that you're using Xcode 5? Would the question be different if you used `emacs` and `make` to compile and deploy your application? I guess no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you eventually reach the date and time you want, you can either start a new timer (and kill the old one), or just update `destinationDate`. For example, in `updateLabel`, you could do this:

```
-(void) updateLabel
{
    NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
    [datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c: %d%c", [components minute], ' ', [components second], ' ']];
    if (([components minute] <= 0) && ([components second] <= 0))
    {
        // Set it for again for 24 hours from now - 24 hours * 60 min/hr * 60 secs/min
        destinationDate = [destinationDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0];
    }
}
```